# Why is there and extra able column being inserted?

Tags: php, html, mysql, html-table

I am trying to add a column to an existing table and getting screwy results.

I currently have:

```
print "<table border=1>";
print "<tr>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td>Last Name</td>
        <td>Email?</td>
        <td>League</td>
        <td>Team</td>
        <td>Captain</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>paid</td>
        <td>wks played</td>
</tr>";
while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($results)){
if($row['email_address'] != NULL ){
$email='y';
}
else {
$email='n';
}
if($row[captain_id]==$row[player_num]){ $iscapt="Captain"; }
else{$iscapt="";}
$paid=$row[paid];
if($paid){$playpaid="<td bgcolor=#99ff33>paid</td>";}
else {$playpaid="<td bgcolor=#ff6633>not paid</td>";}

printf ("<tr>
    <td>%s</td>
    <td>%s</td>
    <td>%s</td>
    <td>%s</td>
    <td>%s</td>
    <td>%s</td>
    <td>%s</td>
    <td>%s</td>
</tr>",
    $row['first_name'],
    $row['last_name'],
    $email,
    $row['league_id'],
    $row['name'],
    $iscapt,
    $playpaid,
    $row['weeks']
);
}
print "</table>";
```

For what ever reason when I do not have the `<td></td>` between captain and paid another column is actually generated.

The original code is:

```
printf("
<tr>
    <td>%s</td>
    <td>%s</td>
    <td>%s</td>
    <td>%s</td>
    <td>%s</td>
    </td>
    <td>%s</td>
    %s \n
</tr>",
$row['first_name'],
$row['last_name'],
$email,
$row['league_id'],
$row['name'],
$iscapt,
$playpaid);
```

Try as I might, I am unable to decipher how the standalone `</td>` and the standalone `%s \n` are working to get rid of the "extra" column.

Yes I know this should all be done with CSS and such, but I am just modifying code that is in place. I am not up to the level of being able to re-write the whole page just yet. (almost ready though)

So can someone explain  why I need to insert an extra column, and how the out of place `<\td>` and `%s \n` are working with the old code?

By the way, if I simply just add a `<td>%s</td> and add`$row['weeks']` to the end of the statement it still inserts an extra column. I haven't tried putting it in closer to the front of the statement.

Comment: Well putting `<td>…</td>` inside of another `<td>…</td>` obviously generates invalid HTML. That whole script is written in one of the worst ways imaginable. What you should _really_ do, is just use another placeholder to insert a _class name_ dynamically into the “paid” `td`, instead of using outdated HTML attributes for formatting purposes.

Comment: Well, your output at some point contains <td><td bgcolor=#aabbcc>something</td></td> which is obviously bad HTML. Many browsers however try to "guess" what it is you meant, and attempt to "fix" it. So they often change it to something like <td></td><td bgcolor=#aabbcc>something</td> which not very surprisingly adds 1 extra column where you wouldn't expect one. Adding a </td> will counteract this behaviour.

Comment: @CBroe, it's not necesserily outdated HTML. Sure, it's an old standard (valid HTML 4), but that doesn't make it wrong per sé. Just not very pretty, and way less powerful than HTML5+CSS3

Comment: I didn’t say it was _technically_ wrong (it’s valid using an HTML 4.01 transitional Doctype) – but it _is_ outdated IMHO, and no one should be writing code like that any more nowadays (unless it is under very special circumstances, where using CSS might not be an option, f.e. email templates for systems that filter all CSS).

Comment: @Tularis Ok I think I see what you are talking about. Since there is a `<td>%s</td>` and there is a variable that fits in there that is defined as `<td bgcolor=#ff6633>not paid</td>` we are getting <td><td bgcolor=#ff6633>not paid</td></td>... thus the `</td>`. Now how is the non tagged ` %s \n` working?

Comment: @CBroe Whether it should or shouldn't be written like this was out of my hands. A fellow dart-player wrote all of this several years ago. I have recently inherited this and have really no coding experience. I have since learned basic (means deciphered and learned only what is written in the used code) MySQL, php, HTML, and starting to tackle javascript. I figure I need to learn how it currently works and be able to code in that version myself before I can begin to convert it to a more modern code.

Comment: No, rather you should recode it directly to use proper HTML (5) and CSS (2 or 3, either is fine; though 3 overlaps 2 in huge areas). Don't try to "learn" that version, since the original coder has made huge technical errors in coding that, making it completelely invalid in *any* version of HTML.

Answer (score 1):

The printf() command replaces each "%s" with the subsequent inputs. So the first %s is replaced with $row['first_name'], the second with $row['last_name'], and so on.

The issue is that $playpaid needs to have special conditional formatting associated to it, so the author built the `<td></td>` tags specifically for that column. So you can't just put the resulting value withing `<td>%s</td>`, because then you end up with double `<td><td>`, as mentioned in the comments above.

The original code appears to have an extra `</td>` in it. Try the following:

```
printf("
<tr>
    <td>%s</td>
    <td>%s</td>
    <td>%s</td>
    <td>%s</td>
    <td>%s</td>
    <td>%s</td>
    %s
    <td>%s</td> \n
</tr>",
$row['first_name'],
$row['last_name'],
$email,
$row['league_id'],
$row['name'],
$iscapt,
$playpaid,
$row['weeks']);
```

The \n at the end simply adds a carriage return to the resulting HTML.

As for the extra column, that's because you have an extra blank `<td></td>` in the table header row.